# Message Encryption/Decryption Type detection is possibele?

Tags: cryptography, password-encryption, encryption

If my Encrypted message = "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055"
and Normal text of this is= "1234"

then its possible to detect encryption method or encryption key

Comment: Question very vague... Are you talking symmetric keys, asymmetric keys? Is the message encrypted or hashed? What you given there as example is an MD5 hash

Comment: i wanna detect ...message is encrypted using "symmetric keys/asymmetric keys" or "AES" or "MD5"... Is this possible??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a programming question. Please see this cross-site dupe: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't with certainty.

AES is an encryption algorithm. Encryption is reversible if you have the key. AES is an example of a symmetric key encryption: that you need the same key for encryption and decryption of the message. Key is by definition secret, so in theory you should never find it out.

There is a set of "standard" symmetric encryption algorithms:

> Examples of popular symmetric algorithms include Twofish, Serpent, AES (Rijndael), Blowfish, CAST5, RC4, 3DES, Skipjack, Safer+/++ (Bluetooth), and IDEA

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm

**If you know the key** you can try each one of them and see if you get lucky. Same thing would apply to asymmetric keys such as: RSA.

MD5 is a hashing function. Hashing function by default is a one-way. A MD5-string is valid when:

```
regex = [0-9a-f]{32}
```

There also a pretty awesome tool called "Hash identifier": https://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/

Or you can try writing your own: http://www.insidepro.com/hashes.php

For further reading try:

1. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm